# JavaFX: Is it possible to center DirectoryChooser dialog on parent stage?

Tags: javafx

Is it possible to center a `DirectoryChooser` dialog inside the parent stage when I call `dirChooser.showDialog(ownerWindow);` ?

By default, it shows up in the upper-left corner of the `ownerWindow`.

- Windows 7 x64 Professional
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b15)

---

This is platform depedent, since I tested it in Linux and the dialog shows up on center of the screen, but not of the parent stage.

So, is there a way to report this in JavaFX developers team and fix it ?

Comment: I've been gone thru the code and haven't seen the related position, because it is native code. The same behaviour for FileChooser. But if you think that this is a bug, you can report it to Oracle and it goes to OpenJDK aswell. http://bugs.java.com/

Comment: @NwDx Thank you for your reply. This is indeed a platform specific matter, since I tested it under Linux/Mac OSs and it shows up centered relative to the entire screen, but not to the owner stage. This functionality is already implemented in JFileChooser. So why not in JavaFX? Is this considered as a bug?

Comment: Hm, well I think it's much more a "Request for Enhancement (RFE)", but you are able to report it the same way. It's worth a word since there is no already mentioned task in the bug database.

Comment: @NwDx Thank you very much. I'll report it!